# Selecting Faces without Selecting the black dot?

Tags: modeling

When selecting faces using the drag select, one needs the select marquee to cover the black dot in order for the faces to be selected.

Is there a way to select faces as long as even a tiny part of it is in the selection marquee?? How can this be done?

Comment: What do you mean by marquee select? More description required to answer the question.

Comment: the box select, the one attached to the W Hotkey

Comment: Use the circle select instead (shortcut C)

Comment: U can go to xray mode in order select every thing inside the drag box.. And did you mean vertex by black dot?

Comment: That's odd, my default behaviour is what you want.. (Linux,2.91).. I can't find a preference that would adjust it, and would love to, like 3DS

Comment: Afaik, it's selecting by marquee (face dot) in the wireframe shading, selecting by any part of face in Solid shading. For those wanting to see old thread on opinions of development of UI for face dots and see what those are https://devtalk.blender.org/t/edit-mesh-face-dots-poll/5858

Comment: Ah I see.. In solid mode it does work, as long as a part of the face is in the selection. My issue is in wireframe mode mode! I hardly use the solid mode when doing modeling operations as I can't select backfaces.